# Installing PEAR on Debian doesn't work

Tags: pear

I'm trying to install PEAR on the command-line but nothing happens. This is what I tried:

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php go-pear.phar
```

Tried also to enable `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar` in suhosin.ini but then I get the next error in my syslog:

```
ALERT - script tried to disable memory_limit by setting it to a negative value -1 bytes
which is not allowed (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file '/go-pear.phar', line 1128)

ALERT - Include filename ('phar://go-pear.phar/index.php') is an URL that is not 
allowed (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file '/go-pear.phar', line 1236)
```

I found that disabling suhosin in php.ini could help but I didn't find any suhosin-entry in any php.ini-files I found.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apt-get install php-pear` works.